# How to get IP address and port number for client connection to parse cloud server?

Tags: parse-platform

I have a client which will connect to parse cloud. For my app, I need client's ip addr and port number so that it can be used in my app. Is there any parse api available which can used for this purpose?

Answer (score 2):

We've been waiting for years for this but they don't some to provide IP address at all for use in client apps.

https://www.parse.com/questions/getting-the-ip-address-from-the-request
https://parse.com/questions/how-do-i-get-the-client-ip-address-in-my-expressjs-application

UPDATE: We recently started using this API to get the public IP address we than append to our Parse objects:
https://ipinfo.io/

This gives us a Json packet as follows which we can extract the info we need:

```
{
    "ip": "120.151.62.36",
    "hostname": "No Hostname",
    "city": "City of Parramatta",
    "region": "New South Wales",
    "country": "AU",
    "loc": "-33.8145,151.0054",
    "org": "AS1221 Telstra Pty Ltd",
    "postal": "2150",
    "carrier": "Telstra"
}
```

There may be other API's to use as well but this one works for us. Hope this helps.